# Creating a "Read More" snippet on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, code-snippets

I want to have shortened blog posts on the front page only of my tumblr blog with a link to "Read More..."

What would be the best way to do that? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the post text editor, type `[[MORE]]`. This indicates where you want the read more link to appear and works for all post types.

Comment: After I posted this I found that out (actually, an icon in the toolbar that will do it nicely. However, I have a IFTTT script that brings all our blog posts over from our Typepad-hosted blog to Tumblr automatically and I think what I really need to know is if there is some way to do this automatically.

Comment: Sadly not. You need to go into each post and add it the place 'read more...' should appear using the UI or `[[MORE]]`.